# sum of complexity

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, time-complexity

assume you are given

```
A=[2, 5, 7, 2, 6, 7, 6, 5, 6, 5].  

Sum=[0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 8, 7, 28, 5, 6].
```

use O(n)  extra space and **must run in  O(n) time****.

Comment: `unordered_map` should work. Rather than saving the index of the last occurrence of the same number, try saving the prefix sum up until that element.

Comment: *"But I think there is no data structure that I can dynamically create and access its indices directly in C ++"*. `std::vector` allows random access.

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you for your interest, I realized :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use `std::unordered_map`, you might use something like:

```
auto IntervalSum(const std::vector<int>& A)
{
    std::vector<int> res;
    std::unordered_map<int, int> m;
    int sum = 0;

    for (auto e : A) {
        sum += e;
        if (auto [it, inserted] = m.emplace(e, sum); !inserted) {
            res.push_back(sum - e - it->second);
            it->second = sum;
        } else {
            res.push_back(0);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23fd6231aac39830)

The C++17 construct

```
if (auto [it, inserted] = m.emplace(e, sum); !inserted) {
```

might be rewritten in previous version (C++11/C++14):

```
auto p = m.emplace(e, sum);
auto it = p.first;
bool inserted = p.second;
if (!inserted) {
```

Comment: I couldn't understand the auto [it, inserted] part also when I try in vs 2019 "identifier "it" is undefined".

Comment: That line uses 2 C++17 features: [structured_binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding): `emplace` returns a `pair<iterator, bool>`, iterator part would be `it`, `bool` part would be `inserted`. And the possibility to have declaration in `if`.